# nginx error_page directive to proxy contents of a static url

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use error_page like the following, to trap errors, and then read content from an external url, and send that to the client:

```
    error_page 404    =404      @err404;                                                                                                                                                               
    location @err404 {                                                                                                                                                                                  
             proxy_pass     http://www.myserver.com;                                                                                                                                                     
    }
```

This is in the "server" directive. I want any 404 to be caught by this (it is) - and then the content from http://www.myserver.com read - and returned as the body of the 404 returned to the client.

This almost works - but when I try to access `http://myserver/somenonexistingURL`, 
proxies through to `http://www.myserver.com/somenonexistingURL` - which seems unhelpful - is there a way to have it just proxy the content of exactly what I typed? Not proxy the entire request?

If I put

```
error_page 404 http://backend
```

Then I get a 30X redirect (as per the docs) - which is not what I want either.

Any ideas?

Docs: 
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page
and
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

```
error_page 404    =404      @err404;                                                                                                                                                                
      location @err404 {
           rewrite ^/(.*) /       break; 
           proxy_pass     http://www.unsw.edu.au;                                                                                                                                                          
      }
```

This both returns 404 as the http status code, and the contents from the proxy_pass url - but without any path appended.